Ubuntu 24.04 installer is not working
I am trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my PC. I made the  Ubuntu 24.04 installation media with Rufus in UEFI mode. Windows is on GPT partition and Secure Boot and Fast Boot are disabled, SATA configuration It is set to AHCI and UEFI, but still the Ubuntu installer is not reading partitions. I have added 55GB unallocated space for Ubuntu installation.

The Ubuntu installer is also showing a partition table error, but Disks can read and access all the partitions. Can anyone tell what I am missing?
also the disk command in terminal shows that MBP is protective and GPT is Present.
Bitlocker is turned OFF

Bitlocker is turned off

Please edit your question and add this information.


Start a live session of Ubuntu.

Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt install gparted  
sudo gparted  


From GParted, select the hard drive.

Unmount it if it is mounted.

In the free space:

Create a 47 gigabyte ext4 partition, ext4 system.

Create another 8 gigabyte swap partition.



Apply the changes.

Close GParted.

Close the terminal.

Start the installation.

Choose manual partitioning and select

Grub default on the hard drive.

The 47 gigabyte partition for /

The 8 gigabyte partition for swap.



Continue with the installation.



Why do you need to create an 8GB swap partition? Creating a swap file is the default. It starts off as 1.5GB and changes its size dynamically if the situation necessitates.

I always use a swap partition, especially when the space allocated to / and /home is limited and the dynamics of a swap file can be affected. I also use a partition for /home whenever possible.

Stuck on the 9th step. as you can see in the screenshot the ubuntu installer is stuck on how do you want to install ubuntu screen

Thanks for Your Support.
I installed Ubuntu Successfully on my device using the Ubuntu Legacy Installer...

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review
